# AutoMapper ProjectTo<>() ignore self referencing types

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework-core, automapper

Source/Destination Types:

```cs
//Source
public class Client
{
    //...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Client? Parent { get; set; }
}

//Destination
public class ClientDto
{
    //...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ClientDto? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
public class DtoProfiles : Profile
{
    public DtoProfiles()
    {
        //...
        CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
    }
}
```

Query:

```cs
public async Task<ClientDto?> GetClient(int id)
{
    var clientDto = await context.Clients
        .ProjectTo<ClientDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);

    //clientDto.Parent is always null
    return clientDto;
}
```

I don't know why AM don't map the self referencing type `Parent`, all other properties are mapped correctly, Im using AutoMapper v12.0.0 and EF Core v7.0.3.

Comment: If you do `var client = await context.Clients.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);` will `client.Parent` be not null?

Comment: Yes it's null because there is no `.include()` to populate navigation properties. But `ProjectTo<>()` should populate the navigation props without the need of `.include()` and it works, except for the `Parent` property.

Comment: *"I don't know why AM don't map the self referencing type"* AutoMapper `ProjectTo` is just automatic way of writing `Select`. Try writing manually `Select` query containing self referencing result type and you'll see that is is impossible.

Comment: @IvanStoevWhy It's impossible? I think it's a common scenario to have entities with parents/childs, how people manage it then?

Comment: They manage them...hard. Even `Include` does not work fully (loads just one level).

Comment: When looking at "AutoMapper + self-reference" there are all kinds confusing posts mentioning MaxDepth, but none of it works at the moment. Looks like it's had some changes over time (don't feel like digging into that). The "official" recommendation now is to have another DTO for the parent (w/o self reference) and map the parent to it (i.e. depth of 1).

Comment: @GertArnold Yes exactly, I was searching for an answere for 2 days trying everything to finnaly create this SO but it seems as you say there is no solution atm.

Comment: Just try it. Can you project it manually? Maybe you could just one level, but an infinite projection is not possible by hand. If you can't do it by hand, automapper can't do it either